# Accepting a date from user in java and writing it to postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql

I need to write to a column of data type Date in postgresql from a java application. In which datatype should I accept the input so that I can use it to insert into Postgresql?

Comment: What Java version? What did you try so far? Any errors you were given in your attempts? https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before asking a question here please search and research and then tell us what your search brought up and how it was insufficient for solving your issue. We can generally write much more focused answers to such questions. So it’ll be for your own benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `LocalDate`

As of [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221), the modern way to store a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone is the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2019 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
```

This maps to a [`DATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) type in [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL).

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

The legacy class `java.sql.Date` class is now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), and should never be used because of its severe design flaws.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy & modern) and in standard SQL.]